# igraph with fixed node positions and circles enclosing nodes of fixed radius

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I am trying to plot graphs with nodes that represent positions in 2 dimensions. No problem here.

But now I need circles whose center should be each node and this circles have to have a defined radius, because they represent some distance, some kind of "radius of action".

This code **almost** does this, except I need `vertex.size` to be the radius:

```
nodes <- colnames(iris)
#               Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species     
positions <- matrix(c(c(2,3), c(5,10), c(3,4), c(2,2), c(3,7)), ncol = 5)
distance <- 30
NodeList <- data.frame(nodes, positions[1, ] , positions[2, ])
EdgeList <- data.frame(from = numeric(0), to= integer(0))
a <- graph_from_data_frame(vertices = NodeList, d = EdgeList)

plot(a, layout=t(positions), vertex.size=distance, vertex.frame.color=c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown"), vertex.color=NA, vertex.label = NA)
plot(a, layout=t(positions), vertex.size=2, add=T, vertex.color=c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown") )
```

[image]

As you can easily see the exterior circumferences do not represent the real distance for the coordinates provided.

**Any ideas?** Maybe something like scaling the positions so that they always have the same measure and then using some kind of transformation formula for `vertex.size`?

Comment: Your code sets `distance <- 30`.  I don't see what you want the radii to be, but you can specify a list of sizes and get different radii for each node. Try `vertex.size=seq(28,60,8)` in your first plot statement.

Comment: @G5W Look at the nodes coordinates. Radii are definitely not 30.

Comment: When you say "Look at the nodes coordinates",  do you mean the variable `positions`? That just gives the x-y coordinates of the centers. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @G5W Correct, it gives the coordinates of the centers. For example distance from node 1 to 4 is actually 1, so it is obvious that `distance` is not the radius